# Photoshop - How to convert swatches to a color table?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, swatches, palette

Is there a way to convert Photoshop swatches to a Photoshop color table?

I am converting an image to indexed color and I have the option to choose a color table.  I have the swatches I want already so is there a way to make them a color table that doesn't involve using the dropped tool and adding them to a color table one by one?

I see that swatches can be imported/exported as .aco files and color tables can be imported/exported as .act files.  I wasn't able to find any conversion tool however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your swatches pallet in Photoshop, click the little drop-down menu on the right side of your swatches pallet and the select "Save Swatches". Name the saved file whatever you want to name it.

2)  Select menu item "Image/Mode/Indexed Color.  When the Index Mode options window opens, click "Palette" drop down menu and select "custom".  This will open up the color table window.  Click "Load" and select that swatches file you previously saved. That Will then load those saved swatches into your color table and your image Will then be forced to use those colors only.